# Configuration per Service Fabric Instance

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm designing a service fabric stateless service, which requires configuration data for each instance. My initial thought was creating named partitions, and using `PartitionInfo` to get the named key, with a shared read only dictionary to load settings per instance. Problem is, now accessing this instance internally (From other services) requires a partition key. Since all partitions using this method will serve the same data internally, it doesn't matter which partition I connect to (I'd want it to be random). So, this gives me many possible ways to fix this problem:

- Accessing the partitions (in my attempt above) randomly using [`ServiceProxy.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.remoting.client.serviceproxy.create--1?view=servicefabricsvcsremoting-2.5.216#Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Services_Remoting_Client_ServiceProxy_Create__1_System_Uri_Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Services_Client_ServicePartitionKey_Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Services_Communication_Client_TargetReplicaSelector_System_String_).

The following solutions that don't involve partitions:

- A configuration based per instance. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36947126/4875631) doesn't give much help in coming up with a solution. A configuration section unique to each instance would be the most ideal solution.
- Create named instances, and use the name as the username (Basically attach a string to a non-partitioned instance)
- Get an instance by index, and use the index against a shared read-only dictionary to get the username.
- Somehow use InitializationData (See [this post](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/293901-service-fabric/suggestions/17287526-allow-service-initializationdata-to-be-set-in-appl)) to get a username string (If InitializationData can be unique per instance).

All of the above will solve my issue. Is any of these ways possible?

EDIT: An example of a service I'm trying to create:

Let's say we have a stackoverflow question service (SOQS for short). For the sake of this example, let's say that one user can be connected to stackoverflow's websocket at any one time. SOQS internal methods (Published to my service fabric) has one method: `GetQuestions()`. Each SOQS would need to connect to stackoverflow with a unique username/password, and as new questions are pushed through the websocket, they added to an internal list of questions. SOQS's `GetQuestions()` method (Called internally from my service fabric), would then give the same question list. I can then load balance by adding more instances (As long as I have more username/passwords) and the load internally to my fabric could then be distributed. I could call `ServiceProxy.Create<SOQS>()` to connect to a random instance to get my question list.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you are looking for to have a service type that has multiple actors with each actor having its own configuration. They wouldn't be multiple copies of the same service with unique configurations, it would be one (with replicas of course) instance of the service as a singleton, and individual actors for each instance.

As an example you could have the User Service (guessing what it is since you mention username string) read from some external storage mechanism the list of usernames and longs for instance ids for each to use for internal tracking. The service would then create an actor for each, with its own configuration information. Then the User Service would be the router for messaging to and from the individual actors.

Comment: The services need to make outbound continuous connections (To another service hosted externally outside my control), each requiring a unique username/password. Each service then would manage an internal state (Stateless, if the instance crashes it could rebuild it's state), but each service would be serving the same exact data. I've edited my post with an example of how the service should work.

Comment: That helps. I still think it could be actors connected to an external service, have their own configuration, and the singleton instance of the service could still be the broker between incoming + outbound. The scalability you'd lose is of course having the singleton external service, but you are pretty much going to end up in that situation anyway aren't you? By that i mean that some external program connecting to your services has to be aware of their index, partition, etc to get an endpoint, or they'll each have to have separate predetermined endpoints. I'll think about it, I have an idea

Comment: I believe the actor lifecycle prevents outgoing connections through the actor as a viable option. If need to continually ping the actors in order to keep them alive. This doesn't seem like the right approach.

Comment: Well, service fabric creates and garbage disposes the live instances of the actors by itself. The actor's state is maintained in service fabric, even if the actor is garbage collected. so activating an already garbage collected actor has it come back up in the prior state it was in. You'd be assigning an id to each actor (could use that unique username) from your persistence provider, tracking in the service which ones were in use.

Comment: greatwhitenorth's answer is pretty good too, with the caveat that you'd still need a separate service to deal with how many instances of the other service to create up to the total number of usernames in your persistence. those services would be live all the time, regardless of usage, sort of the reverse of the way the actors would work.

I suppose it partially depends on whether the incoming connection needs to have an affinity for using the same instance with the same user id.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure that this is what you're looking for, but one alternative might be to create an additional configuration service to provide the unique configs per instance. On startup of your stateless service, you simply request a random (or non-random) configuration object such as a json string, and bootstrap the service during initialization. That way, you don't have to mess with partitions, since each stateless instance will fire it's own Startup.cs (or equivalent).