# How to add additional key value as metadata in the Applicaton Manifest file for service fabric application

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I need to add a few additional metadata to the Application Manifest file of the Service Fabric Application. Is it supported? If Yes,How?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more about what kind of metadata you need to add?

Comment: <ApplicationManifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ApplicationTypeName="VotingType" ApplicationTypeVersion="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">

either I could get a new custom property, like ApplicationTypeVersion, inserted in this node. Or, a new child node under the root <ApplicationManifest></ApplicationManifest>. Something that i can read from manifest, not a part of parameter, but a metadata to tag my deployed application with.

Comment: In general @LoekD is right and there is no way to extend the `ApplicationManifest.xml` schema. But I have one more question - where are you planning to read these values? During service execution?

Comment: i want to read the value from the manifest file after service instantiations.

Comment: If you have to use only `ApplicationManifest.xml` then as I said before - there is no way to extend it's schema. If you need to have a configuration per service you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023157/configuration-per-service-fabric-instance) question and answer (there a lots of options and links) and may be something would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. The XSD schema is installed with the SDK, on Windows it's in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\schemas\ServiceFabricServiceModel.xsd`. 
The schema for `ApplicationManifestType` does not have an `Extensions` element like `ServiceManifest` does.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-service-model-schema).